# Hiding folder in URL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, directory

I need to hide a folder from a url.

An example:

If I enter `www.mysite.com/Jango`
I need you to read the directory: `www.mysite.com/users/Jango`
but do not want to see `/users`

I just want to see this in the address bar:
`www.mysite.com/Jango`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `.htaccess` in `/` should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^users/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users/$1 [L]
```

This treats any requset not starting with `users/` as if it did.

**Update:**
If you want the rule to apply for only `/Jango` --> `/users/Jango`, this would be an appropriate `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^users/Jango
RewriteRule ^Jango/(.*)$ users/Jango/$1 [L]
```

(The `[L]`-flag stops rewriting afther this rule, preventing possible circle-reactions etc)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me;  the Folder I am trying to hide is still showing in the URL

Comment: This do not disable the location with the folder in path, but enables the use of patsh without that folder in the path (both mysite.com/folder/page and mysite.com/page will work). Do the links still work if you remove the folder you want to get rid of? If so, yo need to remve the folder from the links as well.

Comment: For example :  my login page is located at :  www.example.com/Project/PHP/login.php          How can I hide the "Project/PHP".............so that the URL shows as :  www.example.com/login.php ??

Comment: Should be as simple as substituring `users/` with `Project/PHP/` in the first example above. Now both the urls you are suggesting will work as if they are the same.

Comment: Yeah, the key phrase is "should be as simple as........."       I tried that BEFORE posting here

Comment: Then, is the problem that the shortened URL do not work? Or is the problem that the long URL does?

Comment: The problem is :  it does not work at all.  There is no shortened URL.  The code has no effect on my URL.  The long URL is still displayed in my browser.  The code is not hiding the folders.

Comment: Seems like this question is not asking the same as what you need solved then, @phpnewbie2015...