# Hide folder path from url htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to hide the folder path from the URL but still get the content as the folder was in the path, example:

Today I have: www.mywebsite.com/v2/test.php
I want the use to see: www.mywebsite.com/test.php

But, i do have those 2 test.php file, one in the root, and another one inside the /v2/ folder, i want the user to see the one inside the /v2/ folder.

Tried this one:
[Hiding folder in URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770442/hiding-folder-in-url-using-htaccess)

But at the end user sees the test.php in the root folder, what i don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^v2/ v2%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

- `!^v2/` is negative condition that returns true if URI doesn't start with `/v2/`
- `v2%{REQUEST_URI}` forwards all the URIs to `/v2/` path. This means even `www.domain.com` will be forwarded to `www.domain.com/v2/`

Comment: My only suggestion is explaining the `RewriteRule` instead of just dropping code?

Comment: Don't use `.htaccess`, use a proper configuration file.  Your `.htaccess` has to be parsed and evaluated every time, which is not performant.

Comment: @Brad: That holds good for someone who has full control over server config. That may not be always possible in shared hosting.

Comment: @Brad Which config file you recommend?

Comment: @anubhava partially worked, but it is not what i really want, it redirects all the request to /v2/ pages, that is not what i wanted.

Comment: So what exactly are your requirements? What should be rewritten to `v2/`  and what should not?

Comment: @PedroFernandes It's typical to have config includes for each application you deploy.  So, you'll have your base web server config, and then for any rewrite rules, you have a separate config.  It's just like your `.htaccess`, except that you'll configure your base Apache config to include it on startup.  Therefore, it's much more efficient as the server doesn't have to try to figure out what's in your `.htaccess` for every single request.