# PHP & .htaccess - Hide folder in URL

Tags: php, url, directory, hide

I've made a web app, and left all of the pages (.php) in the root of the project folder. I now want to move every page from the project root folder into a /view folder.

Original URL Example: project/about-us

Original File: project/about-us.php

Desired URL: project/about-us

Original File Location: project/views/about-us.php

I have tried [Hiding folder in URL using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770442/hiding-folder-in-url-using-htaccess) but no luck as of yet.

My .htaccess already has the below rules to handle file extensions and caching.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Update: File Structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific url to load a specific file:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us(|/)$ views/about-us.php [L]
```

Comment: apologies, didn't work and I can't figure out why. theoretically it should

Comment: Where is your htaccess located?

Comment: it's in the root of the project, I'm thinking maybe the rewrite rules in my htacess are stopping the above solution form working?

Comment: In the project folder?

Comment: yeah the root, the folder where ALL my project files are, and it is working because pages load fine without file extensions

Comment: @bbowesbo In the example URLs you have given - was `project` meant to be a folder, or the host name part of the URL …?

Comment: @misorude project was meant to be the folder.. my bad

Comment: Ok. See my update. I tought `project` is a folder nested in root.

Comment: Are we talking about a folder in the file system now, or in the URL? I was asking about the latter.

Comment: Funny chat already ;-) I think you got the point of the rule above. Left side is the URL in the address bar, the right site the relative path from the htaccess file. Just edit it to your needs.

Comment: @kmgt ;) got it. appreciate it

Comment: It was my pleasure.