# How to hide the folder in a website using mod_rewrite?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I've tried different codes, but none of them worked, and gave me ERROR 500, here is the last code that I've tried

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 #ignore folder2 in which I put important files, but no works for the website
 RewriteRule ^folder2/? - [L] 

 RewriteRule ^/?$ /folder/ [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You can see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770442/hiding-folder-in-url-using-htaccess

Comment: You need to check your server's error log for the details of the 500 error.

Comment: Instead of fiddling with mod_rewrite, you should keep your secret files outside the server root so that a misconfiguration (e.g. that .htaccess file being accidentality deleted, or the server's security setting for overrides being set to disabled, etc) doesn't expose them.